# How to dynamically assign a CSS class to an array in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css, html

From my JS, I am calling Apex and getting results. Based on certain condition, I am dividing my results into two arrays(Arr1 & Arr2) and then concatenating both the arrays so that I can display certain results at the bottom.

Right now my CSS class assigned in HTML colours all of the results in Blue(tRowBody) but I want the results pushed in second array (Arr2) to be in Green.

Here is my JS Code

```
getValueWithFilters({accId: this.accountId, skey: this.searchKeyword, v12: this.dell, v22: this.compaq})    
        .then((result) => {
                let arr = [];
                let arr1=[];
                let arr2 =[];
                if(result){
                    result.forEach(r => {
                        if(r.Count_1__c < r.Count_2__c){
                            arr1.push({
                                Name: r.Service_Task_Name__c,
                                stid: r.Id,
                                Count1: r.Count_1__c,
                                Count2: r.Count_2__c,
                            })
                        }
                        else{
                            arr2.push({
                                Name: r.Service_Task_Name__c,
                                stid: r.Id,
                                Count1: r.Count_1__c,
                                Count2: r.Count_2__c,
                            })
                        }     
                    });
                }
            arr = arr1.concat(arr2);
            this.dispRecords = arr;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
            })
```

HTML goes like this-

```
<table class="">
  <thead>
     <tr class="slds-line-height_reset tableRow">
        <th class="slds-is-resizable bckgrndclr" scope=”col”>
           {label.LAPTOPS}</th>
        <th class="c1 bckgrndclr" scope=”col”>
                   {label.Name}</th>
        <th class="c2 bckgrndclr" scope=”col”>
                   {label.Count1}</th>
        <th class="c3 bckgrndclr" scope=”col”>
                   {label.Count2}</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody class="tableBdy" >
         <template if:false={excessTable}>
            <template for:each={dispRecords} for:item="lpt">
              <tr key = {lpt.stid} >
                 <td class="tRowBody" data-label="laptops" >
                     <div class="slds-cell-wrap customText">
                         {lpt.Name}</div>
                 </td>
                 <td data-label=””>
                   <div class="slds-cell-wrap" style="text-align: center">
                          {tsk.count1}</div>
                  </td>
                 <td data-label=””>
                   <div class="slds-cell-wrap" style="text-align: center">
                          {lpt.count2}</div>
                 </td>
               </tr>
                        </template>
                        </template>
                        <template if:true={excessTable}>
                            {label.extraResults}
                        </template>
                        <template if:true={emptyTable}>
                            {label.No_Records_Found}
                        </template>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

the CSS Class - tRowBody is defining the color blue as mentioned above.

How do I change the colour of elements in Arr2 to green ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add another property to the objects you're creating. As a side note, you can do this in *much* less code:

```
this.dispRecords = result.map(
  (record)=>(
    {
      Name: record.Service_Task_Name__c,
      stid: record.Id,
      Count1: record.Count_1__c,
      Count2: record.Count_2__c,
      rowClass: record.Count_1__c < record.Count_2__c? 'blue': 'green'
    }
  )
).sort((a, b) => { 
  return a.rowClass === b.rowClass? 0: a.rowClass === 'green'? 1: -1;
});
```

First, we add the CSS property and copy the fields over, then we use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to rearrange all blues before greens.

Change `blue` and `green` to match your CSS names for the blue and green rows. Change your markup as follows:

```
<td class="tRowBody"
```

Can now be:

```
<td class={lpt.rowClass}
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. You're the best!

Comment: what if you need to append it with other LDS classes?  do you have to embed all of those classes in your code? 

EG:

`class="slds-p-left_none slds-p-right_small slds-theme_success"` and I only want `slds-theme_success` to be conditional based on the item condition

Comment: @NSjonas You always have to do it in JavaScript, so: ```rowClass: `slds-p-left_none slds-p-right_small ${success? 'slds-theme_success':''}` ``` (see [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).

Comment: ya, just seems super limiting that you can't use template literals in the template.html....

EG: `class={\`slds-p-left_none slds-p-right_small${success? ' slds-theme_success':''}\`}`

Coming from React, LWC feels so unproductive :(

Comment: @NSjonas I don't disagree, but there is ironically a huge performance cost for such a small convenience. After all, we can't all be like [svelte](https://svelte.dev/).

Comment: Genuinely curious, are LWC actually performant?  I guess the overlying platform makes them seem slow...  React is still "super fast enough" for almost all use cases.    But what you really get with react/svelte is a unidirectional data flow that makes it incredibly easy to build predicatable UI

Comment: @NSjonas Yes. I can [render 100,000 divs](https://stackblitz.com/edit/salesforce-lwc-wrwda2?title=LWC%20playground) in subsecond time. I've also written a Game of Life simulator that was able to run at very decent speed with 10,000+ cells. In summary, LWC is fast, it's Locker Service/Lightning Web Security that reduces overall performance (but LWS is much better than LS). I haven't benchmarked against other languages specifically, but LWC does fall in the "fast enough" category with some care.